# Gradle. How to copy resources from another module

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have 2 modules: `A` and `B`. Module `B` contains `/src/main/resources/file.xml`, but module `A` also dependent on this file.xml at runtime. Is it possible to copy resources from module `B` to module `A` during build?
I've been used `maven-resources-plugin` in Maven for this goal, but I can't find a similar thing for Gradle.

Comment: If A has B as runtime dependency, the file will be available from the classpath at runtime, because B.jar should be in the classpath when running A.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I start test from Intellij IDEA, everything works well, but if I start using "gradle bootRun" (I'm using Spring Boot), build are failing with FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir '../B/src/main/resources'
        }
    }

    test {
        resources {
            srcDir '../B/src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe there are other solutions, but it looks good to me.

Comment: what is B, is it your jar name or package name

Comment: KTS in sourceSets: ``val sourceSetOfA by getting { resources.srcDirs("src/sourceSetOfA/resources", "../B/src/sourceSetOfB/resources") }``